# Subsurf modifier deforming mesh after boolean modifier

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I have a mesh created from a UV sphere through extruding. Before I cut out the spherical part on the top (boolean modifier), the mesh was nicely smooth. I'm using the subsurf modifier (4-6 subdivisions). As can be seen on the picture below, after applying the boolean modifier, there are a lot of clearly visible edges and the edge of the "cut out" is not nicely rounded as I would like it to be. 
I also have deformation at the sides of the spheres. I'd like this to be nicely rounded/smoothed, but I see lots of edges and similar deformation.

Any help to get the mesh nicely smooth is very much welcomed.

[image]

[image: Deformed mesh]

Comment: I don't think Boolean is a good solution for this case because (although it should work but with some tweaking), faster solution - http://topology-guides.tumblr.com/post/152907366360/cutting-circular-holes-in-curved-surfaces.  ANd your mesh has too many edge loops which will smoothen as shown in the image.

Comment: The many edge loops are the result of trying to get to an "all quad" mesh again after applying the boolean operator. But I agree there are way too much loops. The solution you suggest should allow cutting a circular hole in my mesh, but that is not really what I need. I need this hole to be filled with part of sphere. That is why I opted for the boolean operator with a sphere. Would you know of a solution to fill a hole with part of a sphere?

Comment: It should be simple, instead of shrinkwrapped circle in link above add a sphere and either cut it manually or with some kind of boolean (modifier or Ctrl+F>Intersect). Also the mesh isn't all-quad as of now (at least the end of the arms), and these loopcuts will create problems anyway. Try modeling with less geometry, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cghsG.jpg).